# How to compile QT5.9 Webenginewidgets for aarch64 architecture?

Tags: qt, qt5.9

I tried to follow the README file to compile all module, but after the compilation finished, I failed to find the WebEngineWidgets module, and when I add "QT += webenginewidgets" in .pro file, it showed a error: Unknown modules in QT:webenginewidgets

Comment: 1) what is your OS? 2) What steps have you executed?

Comment: 1)It is Kylin V10 on Phytium cpu;2) I followed this steps:(1) ./configure -prefix /usr/local/Qt-5.9   -xplatform linux-arm-gnueabi-g++ -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests -confirm-license -shared  -qt-xcb(2)make -j4; (3)sudo make install